# Hiding one field of geodatabase for some users

Tags: arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, visibility

I have ArcGIS Server 10.3 and SQL Server 2008.

I have a geodatabase which is connected to SQL Server by using ArcSDE. My users connect to the database by IP address and Username and password. I want to let some users to be able to see one specific field and for others not able to see.

How can I address this issue?

Comment: Create two views and grant SELECT access by group.